# Can you Make a Report, that provides the Number of Employees (relationships) for every Employer?

Tags: civireport, relationships, custom-reports, searchkit

The report would simply be a listing of employers and the number of employees or current relationships that employer has.

| Employer | # of Employees |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2456 |
| Google | 3845 |
| CiviCRM | 4 |
| Taco Bell | 5500 |

It's the same number we would get from going to an organizations, clicking on relationships and seeing the number of current relationships.

This is what I see in Search Kit: (civi 5.42.1)
[image]

Comment: SearchKit is changing fast so perhaps a/ state your version b/ get on the latest if not already

Comment: True - there are notable SearchKit changes with every release currently.  My answer below was from dmaster which is currently  5.45.alpha1

Comment: Apologies - we are on 5.42.1 - added for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with SearchKit... Try [this link on dmaster](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22display_name%22,%22COUNT(DISTINCT%20Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.display_name)%20AS%20COUNT_Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01_display_name%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22contact_type:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22Organization%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.is_active%22,%22%3D%22,true%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%22id%22%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Contact%20AS%20Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01%22,%22INNER%22,%22RelationshipCache%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.far_contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.near_relation:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22%5C%22Employee%20of%5C%22%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)  (Note all the configuration is in the link so it won't get wiped out by a dmaster refresh.)

[image]

Comment: I was able to follow until field transformations - mine only shows contact ID and display name. I added a screenshot in original question

Comment: You need to add 'Group By' - note my screenshot and link have a 'Group by Contact ID'.  Add that and you should get 'Count' available in the field transformations section.

Comment: I did, must be something with my install. I got it to work, just looks different than yours. Thanks so much!